# Preventing SSH disconnect in bash script after yum install

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a shell script for installing and activating a crowdstrike sensor on a remote through ssh.

```
source .env

echo "### Installing agent on $HOST_NAME ###"
scp -i ~/.ssh/test-key.pem $AGENT_NAME ec2-user@$HOST_NAME:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/test-key.pem -T ec2-user@$HOST_NAME << EOL
sudo yum install "$AGENT_NAME"
y
sudo /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -s --cid="$FALCON_CID"
sudo service falcon-sensor start
ps -e | grep falcon-sensor
EOL
```

The script executes fine until it finishes the install. After the install it automatically disconnects and doesn't execute the rest of the commands. How do I prevent this? Also, if you run the script a second time after the agent has already installed it executes the rest of the commands.

Comment: Writing your heredoc as a string to be read in part by a series of separate commands (as the "y" implies) is a recipe for things to go wrong. You do realize yum takes a command line argument telling it not to prompt in the first place?

Comment: Beyond that, whether `sudo` works at all when invoked from a noninteractive shell depends on what you have configured in your sudoers file, which is of course not given in the question.

Comment: Also, to prevent shell injection vulnerabilities, you should be using `${var@Q}` (in unquoted contexts) for expansions in your heredoc.

Comment: Anyhow -- to address the stdin-being-eaten piece, think about defining and then executing a shell function inside the heredoc.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy adding the -y flag to yum fixed the issue. Honestly, this is the first shell script I've ever written and I'm also pretty new to SSH so I don't understand what some of your other suggestions entail.